# how to show or hide the columns based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

i have an aspx page where the columns are shown in dojo grid like

```
 var formFields = [{
     name: 'Cost',
     placeHolder: '',
     required: true,
     type: 'currency',
     column: 'Cost',
     friendlyName: 'Cost',
     width: 80
 }, {
     name: 'CompareAtPrice',
     placeHolder: '',
     required: true,
     type: 'currency',
     column: 'CompareAtPrice',
     friendlyName: 'Compare At Price',
     width: 150
 }]
```

I want to hide these columns for some users based on radio button selection.

Comment: More information needed on what you are asking. Please look at the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code snippet.

```js
//radioButton is the radioButton widget
dojo.connect(radioButton, "onChange", function(newValue){
        //grid stands for the grid widget here. 
        if(radioButton.get('checked')){
           grid.layout.setColumnVisibility(index, newValue); //Assign the index value here . Ex: 0
        }
});
```

Thanks
Srikant